# Can the page file in Windows Web Server 2008 be placed on a USB memory stick?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pagefile, usb-flash-drive

I would like to run the page file off a 512 MB USB memory stick. This is possible with Vista and 7. But on Windows Web Server 2008 I cannot see the USB stick in the drive listing for page files. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about "ReadyBoost", Microsoft [did not include ReadyBoost](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.kernel.aspx) in the Windows Server 2008 products.

Comment: That's right, ReadyBoost is not available. But I am wondering about placing the page/swap file on a usb flash memory stick. It won't let me choose the removable drive, only fixed drives (even if they are networked).

Answer (score 0):

Also see previous answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81008/is-it-possible-by-any-stable-method-to-enable-readyboost-on-windows-server-2008